# Cursor returning too many duplicates

Tags: php, sql, database, oracle, procedure

I seem to have a problem with my procedure. Its for a search and it gets the search correctly but returns me the same answer too many times to the point where i get a fatal error of exhausted memory.This is my code:

```
FUNCTION pet_search(PETTYPE in VARCHAR2, BREED in VARCHAR2, COLOR in VARCHAR2, PETSIZE in VARCHAR2, TS in VARCHAR2, ENERGY in VARCHAR2, SPACE in VARCHAR2)
       RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
       IS 
          pet_search_result SYS_REFCURSOR; 
          type_id NUMBER;
          breed_id NUMBER;
          color_id NUMBER;
          size_id NUMBER;  
          TS_id NUMBER; 
          energy_id NUMBER; 
          space_id NUMBER;

       BEGIN  

       select TP.pet_type_code into type_id
       from dbadmin.petType TP
       where TP.pet_type_name = PETTYPE;

       select B.pet_race_code into breed_id
       from dbadmin.petRace B
       where B.pet_race_name = BREED;

      select PC.pet_color_code into color_id
      from dbadmin.PetColor PC
      where PC.pet_color = COLOR;

      select PS.pet_size_code into size_id
      from dbadmin.PetSize PS
      where PS.pet_size = PETSIZE;  

      select LS.pet_learn_code into TS_id
      from dbadmin.petlearningskill LS
      where LS.pet_learn_skill = TS;

      select EN.pet_energy_code into energy_id
       from dbadmin.petEnergy EN
       where EN.pet_energy_level = ENERGY;

       select SP.pet_space_code into space_id
       from dbadmin.petSpace SP
       where SP.pet_space = SPACE; 

    OPEN pet_search_result FOR select pet_type_name, pet_race_name, pet_cond_name, pet_energy_level, pet_learn_skill, vet_name, person_name, petlocation, petnotes, petabandondescription, pet_space, pet_treatment, pet_color, pet_sickness_name, pet_med_name
    from pet, pettype, petrace, petCondition, petSize,petEnergy, petlearningskill, veterinary, person, petSpace, pettreatments, petcolor, petsickness, petmedicine
    WHERE pettype.pet_type_code = type_id
    AND petrace.pet_race_code = breed_id  
    AND pet.pet_color_code = color_id
    AND pet.pet_size_code = size_id  
    AND pet.pet_learn_code = TS_id 
    AND pet.pet_energy_code = energy_id 
    AND pet.petspace_id = space_id;
        RETURN pet_search_result; 

      EXCEPTION 
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN 
          RETURN null;
      END; 

END pet_search_package;
```

Can you see my mistake ? 
Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: You are joining 14 tables without proper join conditions. Check your cursor query again. In short, you have provided where condition for pet, pettype and petreace table only, what about the other 11 tables?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in the select query, if your where clause doenst satisfy all the conditions exactly then the rows will be duplicated due to a **join**.
See an example below that states the problem and how to resolve it.

```
select pet_type_name, pet_race_name, pet_cond_name, pet_energy_level, pet_learn_skill, vet_name, person_name, petlocation, petnotes, petabandondescription, pet_space, pet_treatment, pet_color, pet_sickness_name, pet_med_name
    from pet, pettype, petrace, petCondition, petSize,petEnergy, petlearningskill, veterinary, person, petSpace, pettreatments, petcolor, petsickness, petmedicine
    WHERE pettype.pet_type_code = type_id
    AND petrace.pet_race_code = breed_id  
    AND pet.pet_color_code = color_id
    AND pet.pet_size_code = size_id  
    AND pet.pet_learn_code = TS_id 
    AND pet.pet_energy_code = energy_id 
    AND pet.petspace_id = space_id;
```

For example here are two tables emp and dept,

```
        SQL> select * from emp;

      EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE         SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
 ---------- ---------- --------- ---------- --------- ---------- ---------- ----------
       7369 SMITH      CLERK           7902 17-DEC-80        800                    20
       7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        7698 20-FEB-81       1600        300         30
       7521 WARD       SALESMAN        7698 22-FEB-81       1250        500         30
       7566 JONES      MANAGER         7839 02-APR-81       2975                    20
       7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN        7698 28-SEP-81       1250       1400         30
       7698 BLAKE      MANAGER         7839 01-MAY-81       2850                    30
       7782 CLARK      MANAGER         7839 09-JUN-81       2450                    10
       7788 SCOTT      ANALYST         7566 19-APR-87       3000                    20
       7839 KING       PRESIDENT            17-NOV-81       5000                    10
       7844 TURNER     SALESMAN        7698 08-SEP-81       1500          0         30
       7876 ADAMS      CLERK           7788 23-MAY-87       1100                    20
       7900 JAMES      CLERK           7698 03-DEC-81        950                    30
       7902 FORD       ANALYST         7566 03-DEC-81       3000                    20
       7934 MILLER     CLERK           7782 23-JAN-82       1300                    10

 14 rows selected.

SQL> select * from dept;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON
```

This query will return only 1 row if all the conditions in where clause are satisfied.

```
SQL> select a.empno,b.deptno,a.ename from emp a,dept b where a.empno=7369 and b.deptno=20;

     EMPNO     DEPTNO ENAME
---------- ---------- ----------
      7369         20 SMITH
```

Here it will return duplicates if the conditions where clause are not completely matched, or less number of differntiators.

```
SQL> select a.empno,b.deptno,a.ename from emp a,dept b where a.empno=7369 ;

      EMPNO     DEPTNO ENAME
  --------- ---------- ----------
       7369         10 SMITH
       7369         20 SMITH
       7369         30 SMITH
       7369         40 SMITH
```

If you have a reference between these  tables then it would be advisable to use it in where clause and then compare

Answer (score 0):

You include a dozen or so reference data tables in the FROM clause of the main query.  But you don't restrict them so they will return *all* of their rows.  Furthermore you don't join them to the data table, PET.  This leads to a cross join or Cartesian product, which produces one row *for each combination of records from those tables* .

Here is your query rewritten so it's clear what's going on, and also so it works correctly:

```
OPEN pet_search_result FOR 
    select pet_type_name
            , pet_race_name
            , pet_cond_name
            , pet_energy_level
            , pet_learn_skill
            , vet_name
            , person_name
            , petlocation
            , petnotes
            , petabandondescription
            , pet_space
            , pet_treatment
            , pet_color
            , pet_sickness_name
            , pet_med_name
    from pet
        join pettype TP
            on pet.pet_type_code = TP.pet_type_code
        join petrace B
            on pet.pet_race_code = B.pet_race_code
        join petSize PS
            on pet.pet_size_code = PS.pet_size_code
        join petEnergy EN
            on pet.pet_energy_code = EN.pet_energy_code
        join petcolor pc
            on pet.pet_color_code = PC.pet_color_code
        join petlearningskill LS
            on pet.pet_learn_code = LS.pet_learn_code 
        join petSpace SP
            on pet.petspace_id = SP.pet_space_code
    where TP.pet_type_name = PETTYPE
    and   B.pet_race_name = BREED
    and   PS.pet_size = PETSIZE
    and   PC.pet_color = COLOR
    and   EN.pet_energy_level = ENERGY
    and   LS.pet_learn_skill = TS
    and   SP.pet_space = SPACE;
```

Writing it this way means you can discard all those little look-ups at the start of the procedure.

I have omitted the following tables.  You haven't provided any criteria for restricting them, so their won't affect the result set.

- `pettreatments`
- `petCondition`
- `petsickness`
- `petmedicine`
- `veterinary`
- `person`